# class function gives garbage value

Tags: c++

I am novice in c++. I have made class named Cache and made an object L1Cache using the constructor. I am passing parameters to the constructor and printing calculated data correctly. But when I am calling a different function within the same class and same object, data that I generated in  constructor gives garbage value. Here, I would like to mention that my all functions and variables are public.

My code looks something like this:

```
main.cc:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cache.h"
main()
{
    unsigned long long Address= 5555555555;
    unsigned long a=5,b=7;
    Cache L1Cache(a, b);
    L1Cache.Calculate( Address);
}

cache.cc:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>          
#include "cache.h"
using namespace std;
Cache::Cache(unsigned long c,unsigned long d)
{
    e= c+d;
    printf("Value Of e:%lu",e);
}

void Cache::Calculate(unsigned long long A)
{
    printf("Value of e:%lu",e);
}

cache.h:
class Cache
{
      public: 
      unsigned long e;
      Cache(unsigned long c,unsigned long d)
      void Calculate(unsigned long long A);
}
```

output:

```
Value of e: =12;
Value of e: = garbage
```

Comment: Try showing actual code for your main() function   i.e.   provide a small but complete (compilable, runnable) example of working code that demonstrates your problem.  As you've described it, L1Cache appears to be a function declaration, not an object, so the statement calling Calculate() wouldn't even compile.  Similarly, a constructor that returns void is invalid.

Comment: Try using a debugger to execute each statement one at a time.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is the time to learn.

Comment: I got success when I tried referring variable of the object with  "this". Since there will be so many variables in my object ,I am still not sure how can I avoid using "this" for every variable?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case in the code you posted but in the real code are you shadowing `e` at some point? Do you have a function parameter or local variable called `e` that is hiding the member variable with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

There's a semicolon missing in and after your class declaration. And main should be int. After fixing that the code runs. Have you actually run the code you think you ran?